# Confused with django urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I was trying to define routes in django app but it keeps showing me error like this:

```
Using the URLconf defined in gptclone.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

chat [name='home']
about [name='about']
api [name='chatAPI']
The empty path didn’t match any of these
```

However I have already defined routes in my app urls.py like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from home.views import home, about, chatAPI

urlpatterns = [

    path('chat',home,name='home'),

    path('about', about, name = 'about'),

    path('api', chatAPI, name ='chatAPI'),

]
```

In my projects urls.py I already  have:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [ 

  

  path('', include('home.urls'))

]
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a Path + View to the base url yet!

This is what you've currently got:

```py
[
  # myproject.url
  path('', include('home.urls'))   # include, NOT an actual view
    
    # myapp.url (included)

    path('chat',home,name='home'),
    # localhost:8000/chat

    path('about', about, name = 'about'),
    # localhost:8000/about

    path('api', chatAPI, name ='chatAPI'),
    # localhost:8000/api
]
```

So if you wanted a View for localhost:8000/ you'd just have add one in your app urls.py
Something like:

```py
[
  path('',home,name='home'),
  # localhost:8000/

  path('about', about, name = 'about'),
  # localhost:8000/about

  # etc
]
```

---

I usually think of those `include` statements like, `prepend blah to all of these urls`
so maybe thinking of it like that will help.